# Master Page Control access c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls, master-pages

In a master page I have an asp:TextBox with the id "txtMasterTextBox". I want to change this textbox's "Text" property from a child page when another textBox in this page with id "childTextBox" Text is changed.
In the childTextBox_TextChanged() i have

```
TextBox tbTest = (TextBox)this.Master.FindControl("txtMasterTextBox");
tbTest.Text = childTextBox.Text;
```

I can see with the Text Visualiser that lbTest.Text was successfully changed, but in the actual textBox on the master page nothing changes. What is happening?

Comment: So you don't get a `NullReferenceException` on `tbTest.Text`?

Comment: Weird, maybe you have forgotten to add a `if(!IsPostback)` check somewhere and you're databinding the master content also on postbacks. You have to show more.

Answer (score 2):

You have to provide a public property in your master as accessor for the `TextBox`. Then you just need to cast the `Master` property of the page accordingly.

in your master:

```
public TextBox MasterTextBox { 
    get {
        return txtMasterTextBox;
    } 
}
```

in your child-page (assuming that the type of your master is `MyMaster`):

```
((MyMaster) this.Master).MasterTextBox.Text = childTextBox.Text;
```

However, this is just a cleaner way than your `FindControl` approach, so i'm not sure why the `TextBox` doesn't show your changed text. Maybe it's a `DataBind` issue on postbacks.

An even better way would be not to expose the control in the property but only it's `Text`. Then you could change the underlying type easily. Consider that you want to change the type from `TextBox` to `Label` later. You would have to change all content pages with `FindControl`,  you would not even get a compiler warning but a runtime exception. With the proeprty approach you have compile time check. If you even change it to a property that just gets/sets the `Text` of the underlying control, you could change it without changing one of your content pages at all.

For example:

```
public String MasterTextBoxText { 
    get {
        return txtMasterTextBox.Text;
    }
    set {
        txtMasterTextBox.Text = value;
    }
}
```

and in the content-page(s):

```
((MyMaster) this.Master).MasterTextBoxText = childTextBox.Text;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
you have to do this

In master page.

    Master:  <asp:TextBox ID="txtMasterTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
In Child Page.

 child:  <asp:TextBox ID="childtxt" runat="server" ontextchanged="childtxt_TextChanged" **AutoPostBack="true"**></asp:TextBox>

than in Textchange event of child textbox 
 protected void childtxt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox tbTest = (TextBox)this.Master.FindControl("txtMasterTextBox");
            tbTest.Text = childtxt.Text;

        }

**so basiclly u have to put one attribute "AutoPostback" to True**
```

Comment: I don't see how this is related to this issue. The `childtxt_TextChanged`  is already triggered but the master's TextBox is not updated after it was changed. Your answer just shows how to postback immediately which might or might not be desired but does not help to solve the issue.